# Como manipular Widgets da janela principal através de uma função de sinal ( C e GTK+)?

Tags: c, gtk

Tenho muito pouca experiencia e estou codificando um programa para um trabalho da faculdade.

Estou usando a biblioteca GTK+ 2.0. Há vários widgets na janela principal, entre eles um botão que conectei a uma função.

O problema é que eu gostaria que essa função (conectada ao botão) alterasse os widgets na janela principal.

Por exemplo: Quando eu clicasse no botão, chama a função dele, e essa escreve uma string obtida de uma entry (caixa de texto na janela principal) num widget text (tela de exibição de texto, também na janela principal).

Mas em gtk, não chamamos a função de sinal diretamente (é sim através da g_signal_connect(...)), então não sei como passar paramentos ou receber retornos...

Como posso contornar isso ?

Comment: Oi Lucas, você poderia preparar um exemplo de código demonstrando sua dificuldade? Você pode escrever uma função de `callback` que obtém o texto da entry utilizando [gtk_entry_get_text()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-get-text) e setar o texto no seu outro *widget* com seu respectivo setter.

Comment: Para deixar claro, você não precisa de entradas e retornos, apenas ter os widgets acessíveis no escopo da chamada do callback.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir seus widgets em uma estrutura e chamá-los de dentro da função que você criou -- inclusive organizando sua aplicação --, mas chamando pela `g_signal_connect()`, e então conectar um widget a outro. Um exemplo de código na qual o texto de uma `entry` é posto em uma `label` após um `button` ser clicado:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct MinhaJanela {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *botao;
    GtkWidget *texto;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *fixed;

} JanelaPrincipal;

static void botao_clicado(GtkWidget *, gpointer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    JanelaPrincipal janela;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    janela.window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(janela.window), "Minha Janela");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(janela.window), 300, 80);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(janela.window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    janela.fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(janela.window), janela.fixed);

    janela.texto = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(janela.fixed), janela.texto, 15, 15);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(janela.texto, 90, 30);

    janela.botao = gtk_button_new_with_label("Botão");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(janela.fixed), janela.botao, 115, 15);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(janela.botao, 80, 30);

    janela.label = gtk_label_new("Label");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(janela.fixed), janela.label, 190, 15);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(janela.label, 100, 30);

    /* Sinais */
    g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(janela.botao), (gpointer) "clicked", 
        G_CALLBACK(botao_clicado), &janela);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(janela.window), "destroy", 
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(janela.window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

/* Função chamada */
static void botao_clicado(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_label_set_text( GTK_LABEL( ((JanelaPrincipal *)data) -> label ),
                (gchar *)gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY( ((JanelaPrincipal *)data)  -> texto)) );
}
```

Analise a função `botao_clicado()` e a `g_signal_connect()`, é entre elas que ocorre a "comunicação" dos widgets.